# Koala gem posting twice to Facebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm using Koala to post to users' walls. But posts are showing up twice on my FB test user's wall.

The thing is, when I delete one of the two identical FB posts that are created, both get deleted. So it appears to be a problem on FB's end. Any ideas why individual posts are showing up twice on FB?

```
  def post_to_fb
    if !fb_shared.present?
      token = user.oauth_token
      @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(token)
      result = @graph.put_connections(user.uid, "feed", message: "Test message")
    else
      return nil
    end
  end
```

## Edit

Also- if I try to post this same message again, Koala detects the duplicate post and prevents it from posting:

```
Koala::Facebook::ClientError: type: OAuthException, code: 506, error_subcode: 1455006, message: Duplicate status message, error_user_title: Duplicate Status Update, error_user_msg: This status update is identical to the last one you posted. Try posting something different, or delete your previous update.
```

... so I'm pretty sure my code / Koala is not posting twice.

## Edit 2

Turns out this is only happens if it is the user's first ever feed post. If I post another message, FB deletes the first duplicated message, and displays only one copy of the second message, as expected...

Not a big deal, but would be nice to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It is the Facebook way to avoid spamming not to make you post the same status more than one time, I tried to test the same thing after around 10 minutes and it worked, Hope this would help.